# Importing large .sql file stops before even midway and starts deleting

Tags: mysql-5.5, import, delete

Okay so i'm trying to import my minecraft servers .sql file into database and after first 1GB of importing data it stops without error and starts deleting what already has been imported

any ideas?

http://gyazo.com/15ea06892757f7cdc93a577869b3446b current progress of importing

E: server info:
MySQL 5.5.31+ubuntu0.12.04.2
PHP 5.4.17-1~precise+1
Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 x64 LTS, no desktop, was fully updated before 2013-07-23

E!!! NOW it happent at this point: http://gyazo.com/772c8ae9dcd8194d31f2efa8bcc563c2

Comment: 10.1 million rows now imported... still no problem this time... (1.3GB) i'll keep monitoring it

Comment: please someone answer something this problem is keeping our server offline and if we can't find solution to this we dont have any other choises than just reset whole Minecraft server and whole Minecraft database